# "Installation of apps is prohibited by a policy on the device." error when running an Xcode 6 app on an iPad (iOS 8)

Tags: xcode, ipad, swift, ios8

I've been developing an app on my iPhone recently and today I upgraded our iPad to iOS 8 so I could test the app on it.  Xcode gave me the following error, though:

[image: "Installation of apps is prohibited by a policy on the device."]

Any ideas what could be causing this error?

Comment: You may have parental controls enabled, or a custom policy installed. You can download [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465) to see which policies are installed.

Comment: Are you using an app to limit screentime e.g. OurPact? Make sure there is nothing restricting device use from either from the device itself or remotely by an admin.

Answer (score 8):

Try checking restrictions in your device Settings.

Answer (score 3):

Recently in XCode 10.1, while attempting to run a project on a device, was presented with this same message.

In iOS 12.1.3, the device setting to allow installation of the app, is:

Settings->Screen Time->Content and Privacy Restrictions->iTunes and App Store Purchases->Installing Apps-->Allow